# Validation of error bars with Gaussian process regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn, error, gaussian-process

I have a set of noisy data that I am fitting using Gaussian process regression (GPR) with Python's sklearn package using the treatment found [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/gaussian_process/plot_gpr_noisy_targets.html). Below is an example where the error bars on the observational data is simply 20% of the actual value, and the kernel used is just a squared exponential (i.e. radial basis function):

[image]

It's a fairly straightforward approach, and the computed prediction appears to fit the data well. But the computed error bars (which are plotted at $1.96\sigma$) are nearly invisible on the plot. Here is the output when I instead plot error bars of $50\sigma$:

[image]

The mean fit looks all right, but results for error bars just look incorrect. Should not the $\sigma$ computed by GPR be significantly larger than what's displayed based on the spread and error bars of the original data? It appears the error bars are severely underestimated. Also, why are the errors computed by GPR largest at the tails but quite a bit smaller around $X \approx 20$ where there is greater spread in the data?

---

### Basic Code

For reference, the following code uses Python's sklearn, and full datasets are provided [here](http://m.uploadedit.com/bbtc/154058921037.txt) where the text file can simply be downloaded and used with the below code (which calls this text file and should be named 'output.txt'):

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import RBF, ConstantKernel as C
import matplotlib 
matplotlib.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
matplotlib.rcParams['text.latex.unicode'] = True
import json
with open("output.txt", "r") as infile:
    inputs = json.load(infile)

np.random.seed(1) 

# Instantiate a Gaussian Process model
kernel = C(1., (1e-1, 1e1))* RBF(10, (1e0, 1e2))  
jump_ind = 1000 #skips ever n elements

X = np.array(inputs[0])
y = np.array(inputs[1])
inds = X.argsort()
X = X[inds]
X = np.atleast_2d(X).T  

total_noise = 0.2*((np.abs(y)))# + np.abs(noise)#np.sqrt(y)#np.abs(np.max(y) - np.min(y)) #np.abs(dy),

# Instantiate a Gaussian Process model
gp = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel, alpha = total_noise,
                              n_restarts_optimizer=100)
# Fit to data using Maximum Likelihood Estimation of the parameters
gp.fit(X, y) 

total_noise = 0.2*((np.abs(y)))# + np.abs(noise)#np.sqrt(y)#np.abs(np.max(y) - np.min(y)) #np.abs(dy),

# Make the prediction on the meshed x-axis (ask for MSE as well)
x_input_range = np.linspace(np.min(X),np.max(X),jump_ind)
x_range = np.atleast_2d(x_input_range).T 

y_pred, sigma = gp.predict(x_range, return_std=True)  
# Plot the function, the prediction and the 95% confidence interval based on
# the MSE

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots() 
ax1.errorbar(X.ravel(), y, total_noise, fmt='g.', markersize=10, label=u'Observations (Average)')
lns1 = ax1.plot(x_range, y_pred, 'r-', label=u'Prediction')
ax1.fill(np.concatenate([x_range, x_range[::-1]]),
         np.concatenate([y_pred - 1.9600 * sigma,
                        (y_pred + 1.9600 * sigma)[::-1]]),
         alpha=.1, fc='r', ec='None', label='95% confidence interval')

ax1.set_ylabel('$V$') 
ax1.set_xlabel('$X$') 
lns = lns1#+lns2
labs = [l.get_label() for l in lns] 
ax1.legend(lns, labs, bbox_to_anchor=(1.08, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.) 
ax1.legend(loc='upper left') 
plt.show()
```

with the following output:

`In[1]: gp.kernel`

`Out[1]: 1**2 * RBF(length_scale=10)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the covariance that you're using is improper. When you set `alpha = 0.2 * np.abs(y)`, what you're doing is using a covariance function that looks like:

$$k(x_i, x_j) = RBF(x_i, x_j) + 0.2 *y_i * \mathcal I (x_i * x_j)$$

What's happening here is that the ***variance*** of each data point is set to be $0.2 * y_i$ - which is a ***standard deviation*** of $0.447 * sqrt(y_i)$. Assuming that the error bars are plotted as $y_i \pm 2\sigma$, if $y_i = 80$, then $2\sigma = 8.0$. So, I believe that after training, this effect is exacerbated if you observe the predicted $\sigma$s.

My suggestion is that you add a `WhiteKernel` (as that would include a trainable error term into your GP) and post the results of that. If the effect is still there, I'll edit my answer.

---

By the way, in my opinion, it isn't (statistically) nice to directly feed in the covariances that depend on $y$ because, in the model, $y$ exists on both sides of the sampling statement:

$$y \sim \mathcal N(0, \Sigma(y))$$

You should consider transforming the problem into one which avoids this dependance, although to get initial answers, it's probably reasonable. I can expand on this if you wish.

Comment: I made the suggested change (i.e. `alpha = total_noise**2`) but this did not appear to improve the fit. [Here is the output](https://imgur.com/a/MdxxOHA) and you'll notice the fit is actually worse. I've updated the code to be a full example. 

That is a good point about the left-hand and right-hand side dependence on the dependent variable, $y$. Based on the data acquisition, though, the error should be dependent on the magnitude of $y$. Are there recommended ways to get around this? Is it truly problematic?

Comment: I'm throwing guesses in the air, but what if you add a `ConstantKernel() * WhiteKernel()` to your kernel with the appropriate parameters? (The guess being that adding a diagonal term using `alpha` is treated as an untrainable set of params)

Comment: Adding `ConstantKernel() * WhiteKernel()` appears to help considerably. Could you possibly expand upon why the first term of the kernel (i.e. `C(1., (1e-1, 1e1))* RBF(10, (1e0, 1e2)`) which involves 2 hyperparameters) is not sufficient? Perhaps I misinterpreting the effect of these hyperparameters on the computed error, but an explanation of why the 2 hyperparameters lead to high bias and limited degrees of freedom for the fit would resolve my question in understanding what *valid* error bars from GPR actually are.

Comment: The RBF essentially enforces continuity - it can never describe _errors_ so the constant leading the RBF essentially changes its scale w.r.t. the y-axis. You can interpret a GP with an RBF +White Kernel as an addition of two GPs, one which is the smooth mean function due to RBF and one is an error term due to the White Kernel

Comment: I talk a little bit more about this in [my answer to another post here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/372518/211930).

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Just a final related question: is there a reason why it has to be `ConstantKernel() * WhiteKernel()`? Why not just `WhiteKernel()`? Isn't the constant kernel similarly a constant multiplied by the identity matrix in sklearn?

Comment: Ahhh you're right, yes, that's just me being slow! Yes, you're absolutely right!

Comment: In theory, I believe that's how it should be implemented, although I'm not quite sure that is necessarily the case for sklearn. For example, if I add `C(1., (1e-3, 1e3))` instead of `WhiteKernel(1., (1e-3, 1e3))`, I get very different results.

Comment: Yes you would - you can replace Constant * White with White but you can't replace White with Constant. The reasoning is that a constant kernel is always a constant, so adding a constant kernel would add a constant to _every_ element in your covariance matrix. However, the white kernel will only add a constant to the diagonal. The reason for why the White is used, is to make $ Cor(y_x, y_{x + \delta}) << 1 $

Comment: One other thing, try centering your data (so that the mean is 0), as this is one of the assumptions made in the background when using sklearn.

Comment: In sklearn, "the prior mean is assumed to be constant and zero (for normalize_y=False) or the training data’s mean (for normalize_y=True)." Thanks for alerting this to me--I'll incorporate this change. Also, with regards to the original data's error being dependent on $y$, any suggestions on how alpha should be treated?

Comment: That's an interesting problem for sure. If the error must depend on y, perhaps fitting a GP to the log of the process is one way to go (but it makes analysis harder, you'd have to be careful with the jacobians and such, I talk about that in a [comment here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/372571/adding-positivity-constraint-to-gp#comment701552_372571)). This is because if the error is constant in $\log(y)$, they'd presumably be larger for larger $y$.

Comment: Would you happen to know how sklearn currently handles alpha with a dependence on $y$? I'm thinking of possibly running an iterative scheme myself, but just having trouble finding documentation on how this is handled currently by sklearn.

Comment: The 'alpha' is simply an (untrainable/constant) vector that's added onto the diagonal of the covariance matrix. So it wouldn't 'know' about the dependence on $y$. So, your solution will be approximately correct.

Comment: alpha is treated the same as simply adding WhiteNoise, but I'm misunderstand how `alpha = y` influence results. In my case, wouldn't the values added to the diagonal of the covariance matrix be dependent on $y$ (which is not simply a constant but is instead an array of known data points) as opposed to simply adding an identity matrix multiplied by a constant for WhiteNoise? This kind of makes sense for the training data as I've specified $y$ at each of the training points, $x$. But for a new prediction at $x^*$, I am unsure of how alpha is treated when computing the covariance for ($x^*,y^*)$.

Comment: Alpha is treated as a constant (it isn't changed during training), but a white noise kernel has the effect of changing the constant while training. As for the other question: feeding in a function of y into the covariance doesn't have any influence over training. What you've done is a very reasonable was to get good results. The reason for my concern in doing that is, you have a model in mind (the variance has to be larger for larger y). The model won't _know_ that this is what you were trying to achieve.

Comment: That makes sense. Yep, I've noticed this in the output since the computed standard deviation is fairly uniform throughout the entire range, yet ideally I would want that error to be greater where $y^*$ is larger. This seems to be a fairly general problem (i.e. regression with output dependent errors). Are there kernels/methods for such a purpose? I can start a separate question.